# is there a linux equivalent/port to freebsd hwpmc?

Tags: linux, profiling, valgrind, freebsd

currently I use valgrind. but i look something that does no effect the execution of the program.

Comment: just saw that Intel's vtunes is an option. any chance for an open source one?

Comment: try to describe what exactly hwpmc is in your question.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=freebsd+hwpmc gives this: http://people.freebsd.org/~jkoshy/projects/perf-measurement/

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be looking for a Linux tool to acces hardware performance counters.

The Linux "standard" is [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/), and for newer kernels, [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: The oprofile is mature, but suffers from being developed outside the kernel, while needing kernel module to work.

The perf is developed as part of the kernel, but it is very new (hence immature by definition).